# Rewriting a Protocol buffers response in Charles. No 'desc' parameter specified in Content-Type header

Tags: protocol-buffers, charles-proxy, proto

I need to rewrite a response of type `application/x-protobuf`. In Charles I see that the uncompressed response doesn't come in a human-friendly format. It looks like this:

```
1 {
  3: "328283785jkskj2"
  4: "wejvjwevjjewjkfvj"
  5: "43858934948358934898989"
  6 {
    6: 49
    6: 80
    6: 48
    6: 0x2120323032303031
    6: 0x2029363139333830
  }
  7 {
    1 {
      1: 0x2fb0751a
      2: 0x41cf8894
    }
  }
```

I also see the message "No 'desc' parameter specified in Content-Type header" above the response section in Charles. The request is performed by a third-party library, and the library doesn't come with any `*.proto` files.

What's the point in concealing the data like that?
Is there any chance to restore (to analyse and rewrite subsequently) the content without its `*.proto` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the `*.proto` file.
Problem solved.